# JBoss change the deployment marker file location

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

By default, JBoss creates abc.war.deployed marker file for a deployed war file abc.war in deployment directory on successful deployment.

Is it possible to change this? I mean just the marker file location. I think entire deployment directory can be changed. But I would like to change just the marker file location.

I am using JBoss 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change that as each marker file has a sense for the deployment scanner. One way to avoid that is not to deploy using the deployment scanner but using the management API (via jboss-cli deploy command or HAL).

Answer (score 1):

The Wildfly Deployment Scanner (which very likely is being used verbatim in JBoss) does not provide configuration to change or avoid the deployment marker files.

https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/Admin_Guide.html#Deployment_Scanner

But what you definitely can do is to disable the JBoss deployment scanner, then tell the JBoss microkernel to use a subsystem that you provide: Your own, tweaked version of the deployment scanner. It will have all the features that you implement.

BTW, why do you want to get rid of the marker files?

Comment: My jboss AS will be running inside a container. So, scanner doesn't make sense here as war files are bundled inside the image. I am trying to find a way to disable this marker file generation or atleast move it to a location in a empty dir volume which I have mounted.

Comment: I have seen many JBosses and Wildflys running in containers. Their attitude to write into the deployment directory was never a showstopper. Is it possible you want to write-protect that directory?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to enable read-only root filesystem flag. When I do that, deployment is failing as marker file creation is failing. Deployment dir will be marked as read only in this case. So, I am trying to find a way to make jboss write this marker file else where like a mounted volume path to overcome this

Comment: While I could not find proof that the `.deployment` file extensions are hardcoded, I found evidence the unit test works on hardcoded value: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/3eaeac0b07b4a03917f94bfb8368b6ee09c12530/testsuite/integration/basic/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/integration/management/cli/DeploymentScannerTestCase.java#L111

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. It seems what I am looking for is not possible.